# Arduino code equivalent for python code binascii.unhexlify command

Tags: arduino-uno, python

I want to convert a hexadecimal string or an array of bytes to binary data.
For example, if i have a string like
`'424D368403'`
my output should be like
`b'BM6\x84\x03'`
The python code `binascii.unhexlify('424D368403')` gives the correct output.
But, I want to do this in arduino code.
Can someone help me in creating an arduino code / command in getting desired output?

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/77974/4143

Comment: @Majenko, even if the answer is almost the same, the questions are different. but this question is better. maybe adapt the answer here?